# How do I stub/mock out a call to the base class inside my method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, stub

I have a method I need to test and inside the method there is a call to the same base class method. To write a unit test do I need to mock/stub out this 'base.ResolveDate(comparisonSeries, targetDate)' method? How would I do it? I don't think extracting out an interface here would work!

```
public override DateTime ResolveDate(ISeries comparisonSeries, DateTime targetDate)
{
    if (comparisonSeries == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("comparisonSeries");
    }

    switch (comparisonSeries.Key)
    {
        case SeriesKey.R1:
        case SeriesKey.R2:
        case SeriesKey.R3:
        case SeriesKey.R4:
        case SeriesKey.R5:
            return DateHelper.PreviousOrCurrentQuarterEnd(targetDate);
    }

    return base.ResolveDate(comparisonSeries, targetDate);
}
```

Comment: Why you want to do that? Why not unit test along with the base class? According to me, even if you test it with base class, it will still be a unit test.

Comment: I think for this you would have to use TypeMock or Microsoft Fakes.  Another option is to use composition instead of inheritance (with a common interface), and then the `base.ResolveDate` would instead be a dependency in the class you're trying to test.

Comment: In terms of unit testing, should I traverse into my base.ResolveDate() to perform the unit test on the child class ResolveDate()? Wouldn't I just want to test whats inside the child class ResolveDate() without going into any other classes?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you are doing right thing by wanting to stub or zero-out the base call. However, I have a solution for your problem. My solution is based on the assumption that your class is not sealed and it is public.

The solution is to move base.ResolveDate() call in a new protected virtual method. By doing that, you will easily be able to remove base.ResolveDate() call. In your test code you have to derive a new class from your class for the purpose of unit testing and then override the newly added protected virtual method to no-op.

After refactoring your production code, this is how it should look:

```
public class MyClass : SomeBaseClass
{
    public override DateTime ResolveDate(object someinput)
    {
        if (ConditionMet(someinput))
            return ResolveDateMyLogic(someinput);

        return ResolveDateUsingBaseLogic(someinput);
    }

    private bool ConditionMet(object someInput)
    {
        return true;
    }

    private DateTime ResolveDateMyLogic(object someinput)
    {
        return DateTime.Now;
    }

    protected virtual DateTime ResolveDateUsingBaseLogic(object someinput)
    {
        return base.ResolveDate(someinput);
    }
}
```

Hope, it solves your problem.

Comment: In terms of what needs to be tested for a sound unit test of RsolveDate(), wouldn't it just be the logic inside the child class ResolveDate()? So no other methods from other classes should be entered into (unless they are part of the same class)? So to perform a correct unit test, I would stub/mock out DateHelper.PreviousOrCurrentQuarterEnd() and base.ResolveDate() and just test the logic inside ResolveDate()???

Answer (score 0):

With RhinoMocks you can do this (remember to include the Rhino.Mocks as well as the Rhino.Mocks.Interfaces):

```
var dateResolver = MockRepository.GenerateStub<BaseDateResolver>();

dateResolver.Stub(x => x.ResolveDate(comparisonSeries, targetDate))
    .CallOriginalMethod(OriginalCallOptions.NoExpectation);
```